# Reverse Quadratic Formula in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, function, formula

I have a PHP page with includes two text boxes, `id=rev1` and `id=rev2`. Here is the formula used to populate `rev2` based on `rev1` input.

`var rev2 = Math.round((((a*((rev1-c)*(rev1-c))+d)/100+1)*rev1) * 100) / 100;`

I plan to setup two more text boxes - `rev3` and `rev4` - with `rev4` is the input box (essentially `rev4=rev2` and `rev3=rev1`).

I'd like a javascript function that scrolls through the various `rev3` options between `rev3=20.01` and `rev3=60` in `0.01` increments to find `rev4` as input and returns the `rev3` value.

Can anyone assist? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are `a`, `c`, and `d`? What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: a, b and c are numbers. I set them up as variables so that I can use the formula a number of times but only have to change these variables in one spot.

Comment: Essentially, I want to suggest an answer, rev4, and use a javascript function to work out the value of rev3 that would give that answer. Basically work out the equation in reverse. As it's a quadratic equation it's not as simple as factoring the equation as that would give 2 answers and would have to be rewritten each time I change a, b or c.